# SQL Server 2000: SQL Server Browser Service missing

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, sql-server

I have an instance of SQL Server 2000 SP4 running on Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition.

In the Services MMC snap-in, the **SQL Server Browser service** is not listed. I am looking for reasons why this service would be absent.

BTW, the following services ARE listed:

- MSSQLServer
- MSSQLServerADHelper
- SQLSERVERAGENT
- Microsoft Search
- Distributed Transaction Coordinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SQL Server Browser service for SQL Server 2000. Each instance on the machine handles identifying itself independently.

Comment: +1 For more info look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx

Comment: Technically speaking, in SQL Server 2000 the first instance to start up on the server starts the SQL Server Listener, which does not show up as an independent service like SQL Server Browser (meaning you can't turn it off). The rest check in when they start up, if you are running multiple instances. This is one of the reasons that the SQL Server Browser Service came into being - SQL Slammer targeted the listener.

Comment: I figured it was probably something like that, since it wouldn't be possible for every instance on the machine to listen on UDP port 1434 simultaneously.

Comment: Is this answer still correct in the case where the SQL Server is in a clustered environment? I have confirmed that, on another SQL Server 2000 SP4 instance in a clustered environment, there is a service named "SQL Server Browser" running.